# How do i get automatic coloured nicknames in Macirssi?

Tags: macos, irc, irssi

How do I get automatic coloured nicknames in Macirssi? I've found a script for irssi that kind-of works, but only has a few colours. But for Macirssi I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OS X Lion you will need to use the development version (0.8.6.6.459), you can get this from the [MacIrssi Github downloads](https://github.com/daagaak/MacIrssi/downloads) page. The current stable version, 0.8.6.6, does not have Perl support on Lion.

Once you have the right version:

1. Install the script as per usual (place it in `~/.irssi/scripts/`).
2. Run `/load perl` (the perl interpreter has to be manually invoked or you will get an error that the 'script' command can not be found)
3. Run `/load nickcolor.pl` (replacing `nickcolor` with the name of your script.

After that, any messages received should display the name in colour.